# Alternative to jQuery file for AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I have problem including jQuery in my AMP pages for mobile website. Is there any alternative to jQuery for AMP?

Comment: The whole point of AMP is not being able to use jQuery, or any other third party scripts that may make the page slower. Please have a look at this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35607541/530657

Comment: I replaced the [tag:amp] tag with [tag:amp-html]. Please try to tag your questions correctly; this helps to make sure they get seen by people who can answer them.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with jQuery?

Comment: Here's a tip from [How AMP Works](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/how-amp-works/):

AMP pages can’t include any author-written JavaScript. Instead of using JavaScript, interactive page features are handled in custom AMP elements. The custom AMP elements may have JavaScript under the hood, but they’re carefully designed to make sure they don’t cause performance degradation.

Check the [Github AMP-HTML page](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#html-tags) for a list of allowed tags and formatting.